# Strip all the text from a specific node and remove all tags from xml using xslt1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to strip all tags from a xml doc and i need to strip all text from a specific node only. For more clearity see the below example:

```
<root>
   <p>My 1st Semester Visual</p>
   <p>
      <b>Self Reflection</b>
   </p>
   <p>The activity</p>
   <content-block>
      <div class="imageWrapper" />
   </content-block>
   <p id="5fce699db97470099ea6c7e6">    </p>
   <content-block>
      <div class="carousel">
         <div class="carouselHeader" />
         <div class="carouselNavbar">
            <div class="carouselNavbarThumbnails" />
         </div>
      </div>
      My Space Unit Flyer
   </content-block>
   <div>
      <br />
   </div>
</root>
```

Result:

```
<root><text>My 1st Semester VisualSelf ReflectionThe activity
      My Space Unit Flyer
   </text><contentBlocks>2</contentBlocks></root>
```

Expected result: I also need to remove text that is inside the `<content-block>`.

```
<root><text>My 1st Semester VisualSelf ReflectionThe activity
   </text><contentBlocks>2</contentBlocks></root>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Strip out white space -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Strip out all html tags, only leaving text contents -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </text>
            <contentBlocks>
                <xsl:if test="//content-block">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(//content-block)"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="figure">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(figure)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </contentBlocks>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try not to use double slahes as the start of your XPath. It tels the engine to look every-where in xml, so also outside your current match. In this example you just use: <xsl:if test="content-block">

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed But when i tried without double slashes then it don't looks to the contentblock node which have two or more parents like <a><b><content-block></b></a>. Without slashes it just ignore this one when i tried.

Comment: Then your source xml is different from what you show here in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Add this to your code. It suppresses content-block. -->
<xsl:template match="content-block"/>
```

Comment: What's going on with figure?  If you have content-blocks and a figure children of the root, the counts will be next to each other.  So 3 content-blocks and 1 figure would look like this <contentBlocks>31</contentBlocks>

Comment: I appreciate you look in to this count thing but i my case that will never happen. It will contain contentblock or figure but not both at the same time. And also thanks for the quick and short solution.